# How are algorithms invented?

Tags: soft-question, algorithms, math-history

Things like Euclid's algorithm, or sorting algorithms, or travelling salesman problem algorithms. Or algorithms to solve Sudku.

The space of all possible algorithms is huge. So is it a case of a million people each trying something different until something works?

On the other hand most people can seem to work out algorithms for solving simple Sudoku's. Yet not everyone can work out algorithms for solving harder Sudoku's yet some people have found many tricks and techniques.

Comment: How are problems invented?

Comment: https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-ismp/34_pulleyblank-william.pdf

Comment: I don't agree that it is opinion-based. People invent algorithms all the time, some professionally. Some of those people are here and could give factual accounts of how they do it. And there could certainly be historical evidence of how older algorithms were invented. Don't blame the question for the hypothetical possibility that someone might post a poor answer.

Comment: Consider for example [Loh's recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06709) proposing an apparently new algorithm for finding the roots of a quadratic equation. It describes the discovery process, and the history of the precursor algorithms, in detail.

Comment: Or consider Okasaki's algorirhms for computing with functional data structures, some of which are explicitly derived from analogous numerical algorithms.  Or Gentzen's decision procedure for intuitionistic logic, based in the observation that the cut rule is the only obstacle, so that it's natural to wonder if its use can be eliminated from proofs.

Comment: Invention is probably not the most accurate term. Algorithms are "discovered" by people who have: 1-Good brains, 2-Sharp observation, 3-Have spent some time on similar problems. Number (3) can be argued, but (1) and (2) are solid in my opinion.